# Determine the noise energy $N_{0}$ of an averaged set of samples

Tags: noise, pulse

#### Background

I am trying to find a way to adjust the amplitude $A$ of a rectangular pulse of $n$ samples such that, in the presence of AWGN with $\sigma^{2}=1$, I may simulate for a specified range of $E_{b}/N_{0}$ values.

For my particular case, the set of $n$ samples is averaged by taking the mean, and then compared against a threshold ($A/2$) to determine the presence or absence of a transmitted pulse (transmitted 1 or 0, respectively). It is the error rate of this thresholding operation that I am ultimately trying to find an analytical expression for. (Consequently, any insight here would be helpful, but I appreciate beyond the scope of my question).

I believe that the value of $E_{b}$, assuming one bit per pulse, is given by $E_{b} = n \cdot \left| A \right|^{2}$. But I am not sure I understand the calculation, or perhaps even the correct *interpretation*, of $N_{0}$ when averaging over a set of $n$ samples.

#### My Question

What is the analytical expression for the denominator of $E_{b}/N_{0}$ for a pulse of $n$ samples in the presence of AWGN with $\sigma^{2}=1$? (Such that I can derive $A$ for a specified $E_{b}/N_{0}$)

Comment: I was left confused about the statement "However, your $N_{0}$ is the per-sample noise energy, not the integral.", not sure how to interpret this analytically.

Comment: that means that $N_0$ is, in continuous-frequency, a spectral power *density*, not a power. In discrete-frequency domain, that means it's something per "bin" of the DFT. Conversely, thanks to Parseval's theorem, you see it as a per-time-sample quantity in the discrete-time domain. That, formulistically, means if you relate something to $N_0$, you don't sum up over the whole domain, but just look at the per-sample variance.

Comment: In that case, for a variance of 1, am I to assume that $N_{0}$ is simply 1?

Comment: Depends on the scaling of your DFT!